# MS SQL to FireBird

Tags: c#, sql-server, firebird

Есть база данных на MS SQL, как лучше организовать перенос?
Структура не 1 в 1.

Comment: Не подходит. Есть мысль делать выборку по БД MS SQL и потом каждую строку вставлять INSERT'ом, но думаю что это не правильный и долгий вариант.

Comment: А что же вам тогда должно подходить? Руками не хотите, программами не хотите... Какие ещё варианты?

Answer (score 1):

**Первый вариант:**

1. Почитать гайд: http://www.firebirdsql.org/pdfmanual/MSSQL-to-Firebird.pdf
2. Создать нужную структуру в FireBird.
3. С помощью, например, программы "Import and Export Data" входящей в состав SQL Server Management Studio сделать выгрузку данных, с помощью запросов. В этом момент можно сразу выстроить правильный INSERT запрос:

**Второй вариант:**

Использовать сторонние программы, например, [DBSync for Firebird and MS SQL](http://download.cnet.com/DBSync-for-Firebird-and-MS-SQL/3000-2065_4-10969427.html) или [sql2gdb](http://www.findthatzipfile.com/search-16516099-hZIP/winrar-winzip-download-sql2gdb-zip.htm)